# node.js tmdbv3 api loop through pages search results

Tags: node.js, themoviedb-api

I have written some code to build a database of my movie collection, I am using node.js with the api tmdbv3 but I am facing a problem where the tmdb api is returning paginated results. I am trying to loop the pages but it seems to only return the results in the last for loop.

I have tried to setup promise, async, await but I don't know where to put what and run into errors everytime.

```
tmdb.search.movie('fast & furious', (err, res) => {
      // console.log(res.total_pages);
      totalPages = res.total_pages;
      console.log(totalPages);
      for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        tmdb.search.movie(release, i, (err, res) => {
          jsonMovie = res.results;
          console.log('page: ' + i);
          console.log(jsonMovie[0].title);
          if (jsonMovie.length > 0) {
            io.emit('giveMovieToProcess', jsonMovie);

          } else {
            io.emit('giveMovieToProcess', 'No search results');
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

this is what I am getting

```
Fast & Furious
20
page: 21
Still Too Fast to Race
page: 21
LOCAL58 - You Are On The Fastest Available Route
page: 21
The Fastest Gun Alive
page: 21
Fast Lane to Vegas
page: 21
Too Fast For Food
page: 21
Eine fast perfekte Liebe
page: 21
Fast Trip, Long Drop
page: 21
Faster
page: 21
Faster Foster
page: 21
Fast, Cheap & Out of Control
page: 21
Adrenaline Ride: Fast Times
page: 21
Bling
page: 21
Action Man
page: 21
After the Fox
page: 21
Fast Friday
page: 21
Jillian Michaels: Kickbox FastFix Workout 1
page: 21
Picture Perfect
page: 21
Two Fast - The Journey of Triathlon Legends
page: 21
Born to Race
page: 21
Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up realising that the anonymous function was a callback, lol, and created a recursive function that kept calling itself on the callback if it wasn't the last page all while adding the results to a array of JSON's which I deal with in the client side. I know that there is probably a shorter more efficient way to achieve this.

```
function requestTMDB(release, parentDir) {
  console.log('release = ' + release);
  let totalPages;
  let jsonCollection = [];
  if (release === '') {
    io.emit('giveMovieToProcess', 'No search results');
    return;
  }
  tmdb.search.movie(release, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res.total_pages);
    totalPages = res.total_pages;
    // console.log(totalPages);
    let pageNum = 1;
    lastCall();

    function lastCall() {
      tmdb.search.movie(release, pageNum, (err, res) => {
        jsonCollection.push(res.results);
        if (res.page < totalPages) {
          console.log('calling page ' + pageNum + ' of ' + totalPages);
          lastCall();
        } else {
          // console.log('finished calling');
          console.log('jsonCollection.length ' + jsonCollection.length);
          if (res.total_results === 0) {
            requestTMDB(parentDir, '');
          } else {
            io.emit('jsonCollection', jsonCollection);
          }
        }
      });
      pageNum++;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This seems to also satisfy TheMovieDB api 40 calls per 10 seconds too :)